# first item in array from the multiple collection_select is always blank

Tags: ruby-on-rails, form-for

the relevant part of the new form looks like this:

```
  <%= f.fields_for :event_artists do |fea| %>
    <%= fea.collection_select :artist_id, Artist.all, "id", "name", {include_blank: true}, {multiple: true} %>
  <% end %>
```

on the log, you can see that the first item of the array is always blank, even if I didn't select the blank field

```
"event_artists_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"artist_id"=>["", "2", "5"]}}}
```

is there a way to fix this? perhaps, make it so that if the blank field is selected, then no actual event_artists can be selected in that case, and vice versa?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The empty `artist_id` is important. On another form, you may have omitted the artist select altogether, in which case, the `artists` association should not be affected.

If the artist select is included, and you de-select all artists, the artists need to be removed from the `artists` association. Normal HTML behavior would not include the `artist_id` parameter in the PUT at all when nothing is selected. Your controller in that case would think that you do not want to modify the `artists` association at all.

To solve this, the `collection_select` includes a hidden field with a blank value to let the controller know that the form intends to alter the `artists` association. If no artists have been selected, that blank element in the array will ensure all artists are removed from the association.

Comment: so, to summarize, this is normal and there is nothing to fix?

Comment: Yes, that is the summary.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem has to do with the order of arguments. I looked at [`collection_select`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_select) and tried the following code in an app I'm working on.

```
<%= collection_select(:category, :category_id, Category.all, :id, :name, {}, {multiple: true}) %>
```

**UPDATE:**

```
<%= fea.collection_select :artist_id, Artist.all, "id", "name", {prompt: true}, {multiple: true} %>
```

Comment: setting it to false didn't change anything, still the first element is blank

Comment: I don't think that's it. the `:artist` argument shouldn't be needed, because the `f.fields_for :event_artists do |fea|` line should take care of that. and I want to have a bank field, so I need that in the first curly braces.

Comment: I did a bit of Googling and I think that you could try replacing `{include_blank: true}` with `{prompt: true}` or `{prompt: 'Select event artists'}` if you don't need the blank field under any circumstance. I'll edit my answer to reflect this.